# Where in the US are these vowels mispronounced? "got" -> "gat"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, vowels

It is rather rare to hear a speaker pronounce vowels like this, so I would like to know where it comes from.  I live in North America, so my only experience is with American English.

Most notably, I have heard /ɑ/ in "got" pronounced as /æ/.  As well, "no" as "nɛ".  And come to think of it, "actually" which should use /æ/ is being pronounced as /ɛ/.

A more common occurrence may be the /e/ in "okay" substituted for /ə/, /ɪ/, or /i/.

I have found a couple of examples from [this video](https://plus.google.com/117305041156390095059/posts/5eEgqLHCign?pid=5968960380970530018&oid=117305041156390095059), such as "end" as [ɪ]nd.  It's not necessary to watch but may help.  It's not the prominent accent that I've heard, as in the first example.

But my question is where did this begin, and where in the US does it occur most?

Comment: They aren't 'mispronounced', they just use a different vowel in their variety of English from the one that you do in yours!

Comment: Yes, but this is not a recognized variation, as in the differences between American and British English.  It is regional, I presume, and I have heard it from only a small group of people.

Comment: You  mean it is not a prestige variety of English. That's true and it's probably true that it's regional too. However, what it is not is mispronounced.

Comment: it sounds like you've heard this consistent accent from a number of people. In what context did you know them? Any hints as to what region they grew up in? Rich or poor? City or country?

Comment: @Araucaria: Where is the distinction drawn?  Usually, the point at which a pronunciation becomes colloquial is also when it becomes "correct".  But there is simply no reliable way to define this.  Is there a difference if it's done by 10 or 1000 speakers?  If I decide to pronounce all /ɑ/ as /i/, is it not mispronounced?  I realize this does not actually occur, but it's not a false analogy either, as the principle is the same.

Comment: @Mitch:  The US is certain, but the regions are varying.  One, specifically, was born in Texas and spent some time there, but I do not know to what extent this affected their accent, as they have no hint of a Texan accent.  Another grew up solely in Washington (around Longview and Bellingham).  So, I haven't been able to make any conclusions.  They were both low-to-middle class, but the areas they lived in could not be so clearly defined.  As well, I haven't heard the accent from anyone else who lived in the same areas at the same time.

Comment: Is the person speaking in that video representative of the accent you're thinking of, or are you just thinking of very particular examples of  alternate pronunciations for a couple of vowels?

Comment: It is certainly in the same vein, which is why I posted it.  It's the closest thing I've found online.  The others speak in similitude, basically in a stronger version of that accent.  The words seem to sound flatter and more nasally in all instances, as can be heard in the video.

Comment: The person in that video does not have a strong regional accent to me.  I would never have caught ""end" as [ɪ]nd" but at a stretch that could be the pen/pin merger characteristic of the South (she had no other Southern attributes that I could tell. A shift from /ɑ/ to /æ/ could be northern Midwest (~Minnesota). No -> neh doesn't sound like anything to me, just a natural variation.

Comment: Here's an example of a [strong northern Midwest accent](https://youtu.be/4NriDTxseog?t=131), like Sarah Palin (yes I know she's from Alaska, but her accent is identifiably the one in the clip).

Comment: Nice example.  It relates to the flatness I mentioned earlier; however, the pronunciation of "flat" itself is quite different.  Plus, I've not noticed any rounding, such as in "two", with the subjects I've heard.  They do have relatives in Chicago, but the majority are in Texas and Washington.  I would say Chicago is irrelevant to the accent being referred to, but Texas and Washington are not much more so.  I'm beginning to wonder if it was not regional but instead learned from their parents.  But if we take that route, there is still no beginning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

/a/ ⟹ /æ/ is part of the ongoing sound change now occurring in northern urban speech groups in American English called the [Northern Cities Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Cities_Vowel_Shift).

This is a big change in English vowels, as complex and thorough as the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) that moved all the long vowels in English but left the short ones in the same place, thus producing Early Modern English from Middle English.

Diagrams and examples of [both of these shifts are available here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2VowelShifts.pdf).

The Northern Cities Shift been a focus of study by sociolinguists for several decades. It also includes a number of other pronunciation variants that you may be familiar with, as shown on the charts.